# Visual Studio Express .net framework 4.5.2

Tags: c#

What I'm trying to make is an application with browser window in it. I'm trying to make it with CefSharp. This [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/881315/Display-HTML-in-WPF-and-CefSharp-Tutorial-Part) says it is ok to do it in Visual Studio Express.
And I can't find how to do this point: Please be sure to set the minimum .Net version for the project to be at least .Net 4.5.2.
I have installed developer pack 4.6.1 from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=49978). But I still get an error CefSharp requires .NET 4.5.2 or higher.
I have found, that it can be done when you create a project, but seems like that works only for Visual studio (not express). I have found, that express has it in properties - application tab. But I don't have such tab there, I have just startup project, project dependencies, debug source files and configuration. How can I do this?

Comment: why you don't migrate to visual studio community edition

Comment: [Here's](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/) where you can grab a copy

Comment: Just express is the first thing I tried. Community will help?

Comment: This is solved, community edition helped. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Vasya post that as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved, community edition helped.